# Delphi XE4 Parsing JSON

Tags: json, parsing, delphi

I seem to be having a little trouble parsing JSON, but not ALL JSON.  I'm pulling data from Shopify, and when I GET products.json it parses correctly.  When I get a specific product, I get an 'Invalid Class Typecast' error.

Using the dbxjson.pas in Delphi XE4, and I am just learning how to use it.  Some of the code below was taken from an answer to a previous question about using the JSON parser in general.

I'm simply putting the JSON into a memo field, then calling parsejson2(memo1.text), and it puts the results in memo2.

I am correctly GETting the JSON, and have verified that it is correct through json.parser.online.fr.

Here is the JSON output that works with the code I have:

```
{"products":[{"id":11332270357,"title":"Burton Custom Freestyle 151","body_html":"\u003cstrong\u003eGood snowboard!\u003c\/strong\u003e","vendor":"Burton","product_type":"Snowboard","created_at":"2017-07-26T12:55:21-04:00","handle":"burton-custom-freestyle-151","updated_at":"2017-07-26T12:55:21-04:00","published_at":"2017-07-26T12:55:21-04:00","template_suffix":null,"published_scope":"global","tags":"\"Big Air\", Barnes \u0026 Noble, John's Fav","variants":[{"id":48188219989,"product_id":11332270357,"title":"Default Title","price":"0.00","sku":"","position":1,"grams":0,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":null,"fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":null,"option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,"created_at":"2017-07-26T12:55:21-04:00","updated_at":"2017-07-26T12:55:21-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":null,"image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.0,"weight_unit":"lb","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true}],"options":[{"id":13730250389,"product_id":11332270357,"name":"Title","position":1,"values":["Default Title"]}],"images":[],"image":null},{"id":11400089237,"title":"Pile of Rocks","body_html":"Wicked cool pile of rocks from Hawaii!","vendor":"test_titan","product_type":"","created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","handle":"pile-of-rocks","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","published_at":"2017-08-01T09:40:55-04:00","template_suffix":null,"published_scope":"global","tags":"","variants":[{"id":48653472149,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ various","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":1,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"various","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472213,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ green","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":2,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"green","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472277,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ blue","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":3,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"blue","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472341,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ purple","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":4,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"purple","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472405,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ red","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":5,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"red","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472469,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ various","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":6,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"various","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472533,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ green","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":7,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"green","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472597,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ blue","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":8,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"blue","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472661,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ purple","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":9,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"purple","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472725,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ red","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":10,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"red","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472789,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ various","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":11,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"various","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472853,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ green","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":12,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"green","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472917,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ blue","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":13,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"blue","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472981,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ purple","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":14,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"purple","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653473045,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ red","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":15,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"red","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true}],"options":[{"id":13812358421,"product_id":11400089237,"name":"Size","position":1,"values":["pile","hill","mountain"]},{"id":13812358485,"product_id":11400089237,"name":"Color","position":2,"values":["various","green","blue","purple","red"]}],"images":[{"id":28069860373,"product_id":11400089237,"position":1,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","width":4096,"height":2304,"src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/2130\/9415\/products\/20161010_173112.jpg?v=1501595094","variant_ids":[]}],"image":{"id":28069860373,"product_id":11400089237,"position":1,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","width":4096,"height":2304,"src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/2130\/9415\/products\/20161010_173112.jpg?v=1501595094","variant_ids":[]}},{"id":11319164053,"title":"Test Product","body_html":"This is a test product only for testing API.","vendor":"test_titan","product_type":"","created_at":"2017-07-24T16:05:00-04:00","handle":"test-product","updated_at":"2017-07-25T14:20:01-04:00","published_at":"2017-07-24T16:04:07-04:00","template_suffix":null,"published_scope":"global","tags":"","variants":[{"id":48023373269,"product_id":11319164053,"title":"Default Title","price":"10000.00","sku":"11226644","position":1,"grams":0,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"50.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,"created_at":"2017-07-24T16:05:00-04:00","updated_at":"2017-07-24T16:05:00-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"123456789","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":20,"weight":0.0,"weight_unit":"lb","old_inventory_quantity":20,"requires_shipping":true}],"options":[{"id":13711000789,"product_id":11319164053,"name":"Title","position":1,"values":["Default Title"]}],"images":[],"image":null}]}
```

Here is the JSON output that does NOT work:

```
{"product":{"id":11400089237,"title":"Pile of Rocks","body_html":"Wicked cool pile of rocks from Hawaii!","vendor":"test_titan","product_type":"","created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","handle":"pile-of-rocks","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","published_at":"2017-08-01T09:40:55-04:00","template_suffix":null,"published_scope":"global","tags":"","variants":[{"id":48653472149,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ various","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":1,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"various","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472213,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ green","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":2,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"green","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472277,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ blue","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":3,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"blue","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472341,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ purple","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":4,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"purple","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472405,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"pile \/ red","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":5,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"pile","option2":"red","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472469,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ various","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":6,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"various","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472533,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ green","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":7,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"green","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472597,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ blue","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":8,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"blue","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472661,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ purple","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":9,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"purple","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472725,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"hill \/ red","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":10,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"hill","option2":"red","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472789,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ various","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":11,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"various","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:11-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472853,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ green","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":12,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"green","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472917,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ blue","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":13,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"blue","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653472981,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ purple","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":14,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"purple","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":48653473045,"product_id":11400089237,"title":"mountain \/ red","price":"1000.00","sku":"12345678974346547000","position":15,"grams":14,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"9999.00","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"mountain","option2":"red","option3":null,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:12-04:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"44569874345654","image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":0.5,"weight_unit":"oz","old_inventory_quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true}],"options":[{"id":13812358421,"product_id":11400089237,"name":"Size","position":1,"values":["pile","hill","mountain"]},{"id":13812358485,"product_id":11400089237,"name":"Color","position":2,"values":["various","green","blue","purple","red"]}],"images":[{"id":28069860373,"product_id":11400089237,"position":1,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","width":4096,"height":2304,"src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/2130\/9415\/products\/20161010_173112.jpg?v=1501595094","variant_ids":[]}],"image":{"id":28069860373,"product_id":11400089237,"position":1,"created_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","updated_at":"2017-08-01T09:44:54-04:00","width":4096,"height":2304,"src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/2130\/9415\/products\/20161010_173112.jpg?v=1501595094","variant_ids":[]}}}
```

I can see the main difference between the two is the square brackets [], but I still can't figure out why it's not parsing the second one.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
procedure TForm1.parsejson2(s, sKey: string);
var
  jsv   : TJsonValue;
  originalObject : TJsonObject;
  jsPair : TJsonPair;
  jsArr : TJsonArray;
  jso : TJsonObject;
  i,j : integer;
  aos : Tarray<string>;
  sValue : String;
begin
  try
    //parse json string
    jsv := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(s);
    try
      //value as object
      originalObject := jsv as TJsonObject;
      //get pair, which contains Array of objects
      jspair := originalObject.Get(sKey);
      //pair value as array
      jsArr := jsPair.jsonValue as  TJsonArray;
      //enumerate objects in array
      for i := 0 to jsArr.Size - 1 do
      begin // i-th object
        try
          jso := jsArr.Get(i) as TJsonObject;
        except
        end;
        //enumerate object fields
        for jsPair in jso do
        begin
          Memo2.Lines.Add(spaces + '   '+ jsPair.JsonString.Value+ ': '+ jsPair.JsonValue.Value);
          if (jsPair.JsonValue is TJsonArray) then
          begin
            spaces := spaces + '   ';
            if (jsPair.JsonValue.ToString).Contains(':') then
            begin
              ParseJson2('{"'+jsPair.JsonString.Value+'":'+jsPair.JsonValue.ToString+'}', jsPair.JsonString.Value);
            end else begin
              aos := (jsPair.JsonValue.ToString).Split([','], 99);
              for j := low(aos) to High(aos) do
              begin
                sValue := StringReplace(aos[j], '[', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
                sValue := StringReplace(sValue, ']', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
                sValue := StringReplace(sValue, '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
                if trim(sValue) <> '' then Memo2.Lines.Add(spaces+spaces+sValue);
              end;
            end;
            spaces := copy(spaces,1,length(spaces)-3);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      jsv.Free();
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Memo2.Lines.Add(E.ClassName+ ': '+ E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Delphi 10.2 Tokyo parses the JSON successfully, so I'm assuming it's a bug in XE4. You should use the debugger to determine exactly where it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the Delphi code is parsing everything just fine. The problem comes from *your* code. The brackets in the JSON aren't just for show. The first result you get, which works, has a `products` value that is an *array* of objects. Thus, this line works:

```
jsArr := jsPair.jsonValue as TJsonArray;
```

The second result you get, which doesn't work, has a `product` value (not `products`) that is *not* an array, it is a single object, so when you run that line of code, you have indeed executed an invalid class typecast.  You would need to use `jsPair.jsonValue as TJsonObject` instead.

If I were you, I wouldn't try to handle both kinds of results with the same code. I'd factor out the code that deals with a single product and put that code in its own function. Then I'd write two JSON-processing functions:

- One would read the first kind of JSON result you showed, and call the product-handling function in a loop for each object in the `products` array.
- The other would read the second kind of JSON result you showed, and call the product-handling function for the single `product` object.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I was thinking I might have to do something like that.